# cocos2d-js html5 test app on facebook

Tags: html, facebook, google-drive-api, facebook-apps, cocos2d-js

All I want to do is create a html5 app and make it as facebook app.
  I don't know if this concept correct: hosting a cocos2d-js html5 app on google drive and put the URL in facebook canvas URL.
The cocos2d-js html5 HelloWorld app on google drive is running: http://googledrive.com/host/0B2S1JaK2Me0jWnd3a2xPZjg5Z1k/
  But when I put this URL in facebook canvas URL, 
Canvas URL: http://googledrive.com/host/0B2S1JaK2Me0jWnd3a2xPZjg5Z1k/
Secure Canvas URL: https://googledrive.com/host/0B2S1JaK2Me0jWnd3a2xPZjg5Z1k/
  And nothing show up: https://apps.facebook.com/cocos_helloworld
  What am I done wrong? Or should I just pose the URL on facebook wall and done? Haha. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already fixed that issue, but probably there's a crossdomain issue, you should check if it's possible to obtain gdrive data from another server, you should look for a free web server instead of gdrive.